# 'tLooking to download AWS ELB logs from s3 and remove them

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to get the aws cli to move files from s3 to ebs on an ec2 instance. The issue that I am having is that there is no "move' command in the aws cli. It would make my life so much easier if there was.

From a logic standpoint, I would need to create a script that copies the data from the s3 bucket (s3://bucket_name/AWSLogs/...) and then removes the file it just copied. I know that I can set up Lifecycle pieces to expire the data, but just in case the script that copies the data from s3 to ebs doesn't run, I don't want to lose the data.

The AWS CLI supports recursive copies and removes, but I would need to have some type of FOR command that would execute the "aws s3 cp" command with a filename variable and then execute "aws s3 rm" with the same filename. I've searched all over and I don't know of any tool/script that exists for this. IANAP, so I wouldn't know exactly how to move that into a python boto script, I was just hoping there is an easy way to do it with a bash shell script. Any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) for this task. s3cmd is based on boto and supports syncing directories from / to S3. In that case you will have a reliable sync and your local path on the machine executing s3cmd.

For example:

```
$ mkdir /home/user/logs/
$ s3cmd sync s3://org.example.mybucket/ /home/user/logs/
```

After that the only flaw is that `s3cmd sync` has no parameters to delete the source file after syncing it to the local filesystem. For this you still need a script iterating the files which are synced to your local disk and call for example

```
$ s3cmd del s3://org.example.mybucket/log.txt
```

So if we assume there are no subdirectories in your synced bucket this script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
BUCKET='org.example.mybucket'
TARGET='/home/user/logs/'

# Ensure the directory is created
mkdir -p ${TARGET}

# Sync files from bucket
s3cmd sync s3://${BUCKET}/ ${TARGET}

# Iterate files and delete from bucket
for filename in ${TARGET}*; do
  s3cmd del s3://${BUCKET}/$(basename ${filename})
done
```

Please be careful as I just wrote the script from my head without testing it. So it might contain an error…